# php create dynamic html table

Tags: php, html, json, html-table, row

I need to create a dynamic html table using PHP after parsing a JSON file.
 I need this column structure for my table; `Name | Status | Age | Count | Progress | Bad`

How can I create a new row for every 'record' parsed from the JSON file (I can create a tab separated string).
An additional difficulty is that some 'records' only contain data for the column 'Name' and  others for all columns.

So my question is how to add a row dynamically to the table and fill the right column ?
(*The key form the JSON file is the column header*)

Example of JSON format:

```
{ 
"John":     {"status":"Wait" }, 
"Jennifer": {"status":"Active" }, 
"James":    {"status":"Active","age":56,"count":10,"progress":0.0029857,"bad":0} 
}
```

Comment: Please post a sample JSON file to help us help you.

Comment: My JSON file:{
    "John": {
        "status":"Wait"
    },
    "Jennifer": {
        "status":"Active"
    },
    "James": {
        "status":"Active",
        "age":56,
        "count":10,
        "progress":0.0029857,
        "bad":0
    }
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
$data = json_decode($json_string);
$columns = array();

echo "<table><tbody>";
foreach ($data as $name => $values) {
    echo "<tr><td>$name</td>";
    foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
        echo "<td>$v</td>";
        $columns[$k] = $k;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody><thead><tr><th>name</th>";
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    echo "<th>$column</th>";
}
echo "</thead></table>"
```

Comment: Thx, works great. Added ';' at the end of the 'echo "</thead></table>"
'

Comment: Is it possible to sort the 'name' column. I tried several possibilities using sort(), but no luck so far.

Comment: That doesn't work. The name column isn't sorted. Also tried asort().